# Can't download durable using pip in cmd, the built in PyCharm terminal and by using PyCharm package manager

Tags: python-3.x, pip, durable-rules

Error message in cmd:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement durable (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for durable
```

Error message in PyCharm terminal:

```py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    py -m pip install durable
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

(No idea why it says invalid syntax its the same command as in cmd.)

I tried to download it using cmd with the command `py -m pip install durable`. Then I tried to use the built-in PyCharm terminal and package manager and both of them didn't work either. No matter what I tried it always ended up with the error message shown above. I kinda don't know what I'm doing because I don't use python but I have to because of my classes. Our professor told us to use python 3.7 and so I did. Pip version is 21.3.1.

Comment: Please don't post error messages as screenshot. Copy paste the complete error you get when running in your cmd and when running from pycharm terminal to your question. Which Operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 and the error message is:
 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement durable (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for durable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the package for durable rules is `durable_rules`, therefore your command should be

```
pip install durable_rules
```

or

```
py -m pip install durable_rules
```